Is it possible to extend an Enum in Java?
Is it possible to extend a Jave enum with additional values?
public class MyTypes
{
    public static enum MyCars
    {
        TOYOTA, TESLA
    };

    public static enum AllCars 
    {
        AUDI, BMW, TOYOTA, TESLA, VW
    };
}

Here in my sample I would like to extend AllCars instead of having some cars double defined.
Like so
public static AllCars extends MyCars
{
    AUDI, BMW, VW
};


Hey Chris, enums cannot be extended or inherited. Only way to somehow extend existing enum is using interface, like it is written here:  https://www.baeldung.com/java-extending-enums

Java Language Specification 8.9. Enum Classes: "The direct superclass type of an enum class E is Enum (§8.1.4).
An enum declaration does not have an extends clause, so it is not possible to explicitly declare a direct superclass type, even Enum."
